# Complexity of the set of closed subsets of an analytic set

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Polish space and $K(X)$ the hyperspace of closed subspaces of $X$ with the Vietoris/Hausdorff metric topology.

Question: If $A$ is an analytic subset of $X$, what is the complexity of the set $\{C\in K(X): C\subseteq A\}$?

This set is clearly $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_2$, but can this be reduced to $\mathbf{\Delta}^1_2$ or even to (co-)analytic?

Comment: I don't know how much this will help but it seems relevant: The hyperspace of a compact Hausdorff space $X$ contains a natural homeomorphic copy of $X$ in the form of the closed set of singletons. Your set intersect this copy of $X$ is a copy of $A$. Maybe this rules out being co-analytic?

Comment: It is known that the hypersubspace $K(\mathbb Q\cap [0,1])\subset K([0,1])$ is $\Pi^1_1$-complete, so cannot be analytic.

Comment: The topological structure of the hyperspace of compact subsets of some (nice) coanalytic sets is described in the paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02356061 of Banakh and Cauty.

Comment: I think I have found it: In "The hyperspace of an analytic metrizable space is analytic", Alberto Barbati proved that if $X$ is a metrizable analytic space and $d$ a compatible metric on $X$, then the hyperspace of closed, non-empty subsets of $X$ with the Wisjman topology induced by $d$ is an analytic metrizable space. Since the Borel structure of the Wisjman topology coincides with that of the Vietoris/Hausdorff topology (it is the Effros Borel structure), this should imply that the set is analytic. I would like to clarify this last step of the argument before posting an answer.

Comment: I suppose the issue is that even though the hyperspace of (relatively!) closed subspaces of $A$ is analytic, this does *not* coincide with the closed subspaces of $X$ which happen to be contained in $A$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I see, the set can be $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_2$-complete. Take a $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_1$ set $C \subset 2^\omega \times 2^\omega$, such that $\pi_1(C)$ is a $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_2$-complete set. Then consider the mapping $x \mapsto \{x\} \times 2^\omega$. This is a continuous mapping from $2^\omega$ to $\mathcal{K}(2^\omega \times 2^\omega)$ and a reduction of $2^\omega \setminus \pi_1(C)$ (which is a $\mathbf{\Pi}^1_2$-complete  set) to $\{K \in \mathcal{K}(2^\omega \times 2^\omega): K \subset 2^\omega \times 2^\omega \setminus C\}$, that is, the collection of the compact subsets of $C$'s complement.